# Xperia ArcS how to install cyanogen

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-arc

I have an Xperia Arc S (LT18i). How do I install Cyanogen Mod on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that for the CM9 RC1 that was released yesterday? :D

There's two things you need to do:

1. Remove the simlock first! (Flashing a ROM with simlock on could spell disaster)
2. Unlock the [bootloader](http://unlockbootloader.sonymobile.com/) to enable you to run custom roms.

As for the way things are, there's no true CWM recovery for the Sony due to the inherent nature of how Sony does it (Its different!) - when you unlock the bootloader, you're also unlocking recovery **BUT**, the boot and recovery are residing on the one partition so do not try flash CWM into it otherwise BAM, goodbye!

There is an app on the market, for a CWM which is not a real CWM (it dumps its binaries into the /system directory) which by the way, **must remind** you ***need*** root for this!

You will need [se1tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1431033&page=2) (IIRC) to flash the latest ROM, you could also check out the [FreeXperia](https://github.com/freexperia) project for information on this, FreeXperia is by jerpelea, which is now what you're seeing, as CM9.

Comment: How do I remove simlock? I am new to Android and don’t understand anything you have written

Comment: Basically you need the se1tool, adb drivers, and the cable, to be honest, its an overload for a new person like you coming to Android, hence *it would be best to ask someone in your local area to do this for you. * The answer I've posted is a run-down of what's needed to be done in order to go ahead and install a custom ROM :)

Comment: I'll check it out for you and get back to you shortly :)

Comment: Since you stated Poland, I guess this will be of information to you http://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic2302148.html

Comment: How do I _check_ if the phone really has simlock? I don’t have any foreign network simcards at hand…

Comment: It shows all 0s in service menu>service info>sim lock, does that mean it is unlocked?

Comment: I would think so, have xperia mini here... :)

Comment: I just checked and it isn’t simlocked.

Comment: That's great to hear, so that's one off the list above :) \o/

Comment: I followed the instructions on the Cyanogen site and they, unsurprisingly, worked. I did not install the 9.0 rc.